# Can first order linear differential equations contain a function that contains both variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example is this equation a linear one?

$$\frac{dx}{dy} + y\cdot\frac{3y^2-5x^2}{4x} = 0$$

If it isn't is it because I have that $x^2$ or because the function $\frac{3y^2-5x^2}{4x}$ contains both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It's not linear, but not for the reasons that you think - it has a $y^3$ term. An ODE such as $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^3$ would be an example of a linear ODE, because all the $y, y', y''$ etc terms are linear.

Comment: see that it cannot be written that way $$a(y)x'+b(y)x = c(y).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dy} + y\cdot\frac{3y^2-5x^2}{4x} = 0$$
$$\frac{2xdx}{2ydy} + \frac{3y^2-5x^2}{4} = 0$$
$$\begin{cases}
X=x^2\\
Y=y^2
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad\frac{dX}{dY} + \frac34 Y-\frac54 X = 0$$
This is first order linear ODE. I suppose that you can take it from here.